# Add Nokogiri returned XML values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am struggling to think up the syntax on this one.

I am using Nokogiri to parse XML to get `X` rows, each containing the attribute 'convertedClicks':

```
<% @report.xpath("//row").each do |row|%>
<% allConversions += row.attr("convertedClicks").to_i %>
<% end %>
```

Naturally my intent here is that 'allConversions' would equal the sum of the rows' 'convertedClicks' columns.

This returns the error

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This is because `allConversions` does not yet exist. But if I create it and set it to 0 I am left with 0.

How do I create a variable and add to it?

Comment: since all you need is `convertedClicks`, you could just find all elements with this attribute then use (.map and .sum) or just (.reduce). also i guess that you should move the code you provided to a helper method taking @report as a param.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't thinking this through and my HTML was incomplete which explains part of why I was seeing 0:

```
<% allConversions = 0 %>
<% @report.xpath("//row").each do |row|%>
<% allConversions += row.attr("convertedClicks").to_i %>
<% end %>
<div class="conversions-stat"><span class="counter"><%= allConversions %></span></div>
```

Naturally a variable must be initialized before attempting to alter it.

Comment: As a note about programming with an MVC, move your logic out of your view and put it in a controller. Views really should just access/loop over variables and do conditional tests to determine how to create the page.